# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting '`'

Tags: laravel

I develop on E-Commerce website with Laravel Framework .After login in   admin Panel and try to add Product name,Product Price ,Product Description from Product Controller.It shows recurrently the above problem. My Product Controller arises Problem.Give me solution as soon as possible.

My Product Controller.php Code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Category;

use App\Manufacturer;

use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller

{

    public function createProduct()

    {
        $categories=Category::where('publicationStatus',1)->get();

        $manufacturers=Manufacturer::where('publicationStatus',1)->get();

        return view('admin.product.createProduct',['categories'=>$categories,'manufacturers'=>$manufacturers]);

    }

    public function storeProduct(Request $request)

    {

        $this->validate($request,[

            'productName'=>'required',

            'productPrice'=>'required',

            'productImage'=>'required',    

        ]);

        $productImage=$request->file('productImage');

        $name=$productImage->getClientOriginalName();

        $uploadPath='public/productImage/';

        $productImage->move($uploadPath,$name);

        $imageUrl=$uploadPath.$name;

        $this->saveProductInfo($imageUrl);

        return redirect('/product/add')->with('message','Product Info Saved Successfully');

    }

    protected function saveProductInfo($request,$imageUrl)


    {

        $product = new Product();

        $product->productName=$request->productName;

        $product->categoryId=$request->categoryId;

        $product->manufacturerId=$request->manufacturerId;

        $product->productPrice=$request->productPrice;

        $product->productQuantity=$request->productQuantity;

        $product->productShortDescription=$request->productShortDescription;

        $product->productLongDescription=$request->productLongDescription;

        $product->productImage =$imageUrl;

        $product->publicationStatus=$request->publicationStatus;    

        $product->save();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This lines. Please remove ` symbol.

```
protected function saveProductInfo($request,$imageUrl)


{

`   $product = new Product();
```

Comment: Thanks Yachi! But why this error created during debugging

Comment: I need object to call .so i made Object with Class

Comment: Sorry! Yachi your solution not working . The Product Info not being inserted in my database.

Comment: Please pass your request variable, you use method with only one argument.
```$this->saveProductInfo($imageUrl);```

Comment: Yes, you must pass two, if you want to pass one, you must use default value

Comment: To get form info we use $request variable .So  i have used:  $this->saveProductInfo($request,$imageUrl);    But Not working

Comment: You should read document or watch video to understand how $request variable get data from the body. You should use `$request->all()` to retrieve an array of data. Read more about this here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Comment: But where is the problem in ProductController . I have give full code Can you detect Where is problem?

Comment: In storeProduct method --> ```$this->saveProductInfo($request->all(), $imageUrl);```. Then in saveProductInfo, you will use $request as an array, not an object.

Comment: thanks Yachi! My Product info Successfully inserted. Thanks for Co-operation.

Comment: I am glad that you did it. If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as the answer, thanks!